# Laravel how to implement multiple instances of same service

Tags: php, laravel, docker, authentication, multiple-instances

**The Current Setup:**

**Angular front-end** application which accesses and edits data on a **Laravel backend**.
User authentication is handled via Laravel Passport.

**The Problem:**

Multiple companies should be able to get their own 'copy' of this service with their own data, possibly their own database.

**Options I can think of:**

1. Clone Laravel instance for each new company that signs up (docker is already setup). Add Laravel Login Instance which holds a lookup table to determine which email belongs to which backend instance. The login instance returns docker domain/port and authentication is handled there.
2. Add Company Field to every table in the current Laravel project. Adapt code to only return data for the project the user belongs to.

**Goals:**

1. Security: It should not ever be possible to access or edit data from another customer/company.
2. Many to Many: Optimally, a single email should be able to associate with multiple customer/company accounts.
3. Only 1 Angular frontend. Currently, it holds an `api_url` field which I manually change to access different Laravel backends (dev, prod).
4. One login, I don't want to have a company login that links me to the correct backend, and then have to enter another login for the selected backend. i.e one authentication, this should not be a problem if for example the login node just returns where to send the actual auth request.

I have been going through this for a while now and I can't decide on a specific way of doing it. **Any guidance, tips, alternatives, or pitfalls are welcome**.

Comment: Have a look at the [Tenancy for Laravel](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/) package. Sounds like it might be what you're after.

Comment: This sounds perfect. I will check it out. Thank you

Comment: How are different schemas in the databases related to your service differ from each-other?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Peppermintology, I tried [Tenancy for Laravel](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/) and it just works.
They offer configuration to use a single Database or A Database for each Tenant, along with a lot of other features.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33763620)